# What is benjamini

Tags: bioinformatics, gene-expression

I was doing some gene expression analysis using this tool http://david.abcc.ncifcrf.gov/summary.jsp. However, I have a confusion about what benjamini is. I fed it some gene list and it gave me some potential pathways the genes belong to(KEGG pathways). However, I have a confusion what this column called benjamini is. What does it denote? Any suggestions?

Comment: Probably from [Yoav Benjamini](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoav_Benjamini) and something to do with a statistical test of [False Discovery Rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_Discovery_Rate).

Comment: please don't cross-post with BioStars without acknowledging it in your question -- http://www.biostars.org/p/64888/

Answer (score 7):

It is a [Benjamini-Hochberg q-value,](http://udel.edu/~mcdonald/statmultcomp.html) similar to a p-value corrected for multiple hypothesis testing using the false discovery rate.